# If $2^n+1$ is prime then $n=2^k$ for some positive integer $k$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

This problem came up as an extra problem to do for homework in my discrete mathematics class. I'm really just looking at some sort of a hint on how to proceed because I'm really not sure what to do. I figure I probably want to assume that n is not equal to $2^k$ but I don't know how to express this in a way that I can use it in the proof.

Comment: It’s a Fermat prime

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose $n$ has an odd factor $m$. If $m$ is odd, then 
$$
a^m + 1 = (a+1)(a^{m-1}-a^{m-2}+...+a^2-a+1)
$$
Use this formula with $a=2$.

Comment: How is this a "hint"? Isn't this a full solution, with a few minor details left to the reader?

Comment: @Arthur: Well, you are probably right. It is more than a hint.

Comment: @Arthur but less than a full solution as one has to sue $a=2^{n/m}$ for the general case ...

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is odd the $a^n + b^n$ is divisible by $a+b$. Hence if $n$ is odd, $2^n + 1$ is divisible by $3$. Can you complete the proof that $n = 2^k$ from here?

Comment: Yeah I think I can, thank you this is definitely very helpful.